# Insert a new record in one to one relational tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have 2 tables for Users, one to hold User common info and one for extra info, they have one to one relation with UserId field.

**Users:**

```
UserId >> Primarykey auto increment  
UserName  
Password
```

**UsersInfo:**

```
UserId >> Primarykey  
MoreInfo
```

in my application , when the user register a new account we insert a row in Users table, and later if he wanted to change some info, we need to add to UsersInfo table.

The problem I am facing is that when I try to insert in the UsersInfo table it always tell me that UserId can't be null. while I have this userId set before i call saveChanges.

```
var info = new UserInfo { UserId = userId, MoreInfo = text };
context.UserInfo.Add(info);
```

I don't know if the problem in EF or in db, so any info or something to check will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution but workaround.
It probably will work:

```
Users:
----
UserId >> Primary key & Auto increment
UserName
Password

UsersInfo:
----
UsersInfoId >> Primary key auto increment
UserId >> Foreign key & Unique constraint (for one-to-one relation)
MoreInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you need not use two separate tables, except when u have multiple sets of **extra info** per user. If you use single table, then a simple *UPDATE* query will ease the things.

If you want to go your way, first test whether **userId** is *null* or having some value. If it is null or empty, you are bound to get the error you mentioned.

See if it helps.